# Xamarin C# XAML Cross-Platform With Buttons Bound To Custom Graphic

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, skiasharp, absolutelayout

Here's the basic idea of what I'm trying to do; have this (see image link) graphic with roots going into the ground and the roots split off into different directions. At the end of each root I'd like to place a round button with a number in it which will take them to a new page. (the image only shows a few buttons but later on, for updates i'll have more lessons, meaning more buttons, and so the page would scroll down revealing more buttons)

What I have tried; I tried drawing a dynamic root system graphic, which worked and resized properly based on the screen size. But Skiasharp doesn't really work with absolute layouts and adding buttons on top of the SKCanvas. From my understanding absolute layouts are the only way to but buttons in customs spots.

I'd like to have the Graphic dynamic and locked onto the buttons. I'v tried just placing the buttons over the top of a background image that already had the root graphic on it. But, they don't always align properly.

Is there a way to make this work, or another way to draw the graphic and have the buttons bound to the end of the roots? Or am I just stuck with not having them align with a static background image?

Concept image for app page is below:

[image: imgrpic]

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: I think that instead of drawing in code, you could use a SVG
https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/SVG

Comment: Using *Inkscape* I created a SVG from your drawing: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqqOoI2SyeQfjpUAhwW1JcNcmokLMg

Comment: @Tony Thanks, Is an absolute layout the best way to get the buttons where i want them? And is there a way to lock them onto the vector image so they never miss-align?

Comment: @hashimks There isn't much code to share really. All I had was a content page template and installed the Skiasparp NuGet package and drew some shapes while trying to place buttons in specific spots.